# How to pass a wildcard in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following:

```
public class Foo<T> : Goo
    where T: SomeClass<?>, new()
```

I know that ? is not a real wildcard in C#, however, how would you write this correctly in C# such that SomeClass can take any class as an argument?  I tried using object, but then I get an error "...there is no implicit reference conversion from..."

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify second type argument (i.e. `Y` in my sample), note that `Y` could be anything as there are no restrictions, even the same as `T`.

```
public class Foo<T, Y> : Goo
    where T: SomeClass<Y>, new()
```

Another option is to specify only second class if you only need to use `SomeClass<Y>` in your generic class, you will not need new() restriction because compiler knows in advance that `SomeClass<T>` have default constructor:

```
public class Foo<Y> : Goo{
  public SomeClass<Y> Value;

  public void Setup() { Value = new SomeClass<Y>(); }
}
```